# Strange JSONP syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I'm stuck on this odd syntax error pointing to the colon in the first key:value pair of the json return.  JSONLint.com says the json is valid.  Can anyone help?  JSFiddle linked below.  Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/gbkester/hgt8bvb8/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=38.14000&lon=-78.45000&FcstType=digitalJSON",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (json) {
            console.log(json)
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: try to change jsonp to json.

Comment: It's not so easy to change `jsonp` to `json`. There's likely to be same-origin restrictions that will prevent this from working.

Comment: Right, because of cross-origin blocking, I'm hoping to get it to work with jsonp.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't seem to me that this response is actually JSONP. It looks like straight JSON.

Typically JSONP endpoints accept a `callback=` URL parameter. The value of this parameter is used to name a function that wraps the actual object. So, for example:

```
http://example.com/api/endpoint?callback=foobar
```

would return something like:

```
foobar({"key":"value"});
```

You can see jQuery trying this in the Fiddle:

```
http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?...&callback=jQuery11100967190676368773_1409103826888&_=1409103826889
```

The `callback=` is naming the function that it would like to see returned, and the `_=` is an attempt at cache busting. It wants to see a response that looks like:

```
jQuery11100967190676368773_1409103826888({ ... });
```

Adding or removing this parameter doesn't seem to change the response content. Not having the API docs handy, it's possible that they use a different parameter for this. If, for example, they used `bazquux` as the parameter, you could change your request to:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    url: "http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=38.14000&lon=-78.45000&FcstType=digitalJSON&bazquux=?",
    ...
})
```

Note the literal `&bazquux=?`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't find any documentation from NWS on the json response.  The available documentation is on their xml formatted response which results in cross-origin blocking errors.  Any other thoughts on how to sniff out the callback function or otherwise use this feed client side?  If not, I suppose I'll write something server side, which seems a shame.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're missing semicolons:

1. After console.log(json)
2. After the closing round bracket of the ajax block
3. After the closing round bracket of 'ready' function

Comment: If we're talking strict, sure. But the rules for ASI pretty clearly spell out that it's perfectly valid to leave all of these instances out.